# Error code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, setattribute

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementById('subMenu').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
          links[i].onclick = function() {
              links[i].setAttribute('class', 'selected');
          }
    }
}
```

Firebug shows:

```
TypeError: link[i] is undefined
 link[i].setAttribute('class', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 6):

Change this:

```
links[i].setAttribute('class', 'selected');
```

to this:

```
this.setAttribute('class', 'selected');
```

or better, to this:

```
this.className = "selected";
```

There's no block scope in JavaScript, so your `i` was stuck at the last value after the iteration.

But since all you need is a reference to the element with the handler, it's already accesssible via `this` inside the handler.

---

If you do actually need `i`, then you need to scope `i` in a new variable scope per iteration.

```
var links = document.getElementById('subMenu').getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
     links[i].onclick = makeHandler(i);
}

function makeHandler(i) {
    return function() {
        links[i].setAttribute('class', 'selected');
    }
}
```

---

Or just add it as a property to the DOM element.